# Server bandwidth usage with rtmp streaming of video

Tags: flash, amazon-ec2, cloud, video-streaming

Quick question - I have the following setup:

(1) An ec2 instance with an SWF on it - this SWF plays streaming video - i.e. is a video player like JWPlayer
(2) A streaming video distribution set up via Cloudfront

If I stream the the video via RTMP from Cloudfront to the SWF (which is on ec2) - would I incur charges for data transfer into the server (i.e. for data being read by the SWF)  and out of the server (i.e. for data being displayed by the SWF to the user) on account of streaming the video to users (assuming that data transfer into and out for the server is being charged for)?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Try revising the second sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SWF is hosted on EC2, but it runs in the user's browser.  You only pay for cloudfront streaming usage, since the content is streamed directly from cloudfront to the user.